# How to change direction of line-break in CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have `p` inside `div`, which is different from normal paragraph. It starts from bottom right, kind of like this

[image: <p>]

Main problem is when i enter more text line breaks in different direction.

What is happening.

[image]

What I want.

[image]

Here is my stylesheet:

```
div{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: flex-end;
  }

p{
   align-self: flex-end;
 }
```

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want this ? [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e5at9eyf/2/)

```
div{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: flex-end;
   background: red;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px; 
  }

p{
   align-self: flex-end;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: right;
 }
```